# Restart python Script on Server after crashing

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, ubuntu, flask, waitress

I am currently trying to set um a server to run a tensorflow Application. It is working fine but if there are too many requests the server terminates the flask Application which is requesting the answer from my tensorflow model.
This means that the Server is useless as long as I don't restart the flask app manually with `python3 flaskApp.py` in the server terminal.

Is there a way to restart the Python Script automatically once it fails? <==  !! main question !!

It doesn't bother me when I don't get a return value once in a while but I don't want to manually restart the flaskApp once a day.

Here is the code for my flask Application, the method 'handler' returns a probability from my tensorflow model running in the background.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, jsonify
from modelv4 import *
from waitress import serve
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def processjson():
    data = request.get_json()
    satz = data['text']
    print(satz)
    ruckgabe = handler(satz)
    ruckgabe = round(ruckgabe*10000)
    ruckgabe = ruckgabe / 100
    ruckgabe = str(ruckgabe)
    ruckgabe = jsonify({"ruckgabe": ruckgabe})
    #ruckgabe.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return ruckgabe

if __name__=='__main__':
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

The server is running on aws EC2 as an Ubuntu instance, so you get a basic linux terminal.
If you need any more information to answer my question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Since the application is running on an ubuntu server I recommend using **systemd**.
You can let systemd auto-restart it in case it fails or is accidentally killed.

To do this, you can add the restart option to the `.service` file you created specifically for your application.

[How can I run my flask application as a service with systemd?](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-a-flask-application-as-a-service-with-systemd)

A possible configuration of your `.service` file could be the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=My flask app
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

StartLimitIntervalSec=500
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

ExecStart= <script to start your application>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```